# bigqueryで特定の構造体をもつレコードのみ出力する方法

Tags: json, google-bigquery

サンプルとして以下のjsonデータを登録します。
例えば一行目のHistory構造体を持つレコードのみ出力するsql文を書くために
Books.Historyのサイズを取得して比較したいのですが、やり方はないでしょうか？

**◆JSONファイル:**

```
{"User":{"Name":"aaaaa","age":"20"},"Books":{"History":{"Title":"xxxxx","page":"100"}}}
{"User":{"Name":"aaaaa","age":"20"},"Books":{"Science":{"Title":"yyyyy","page":"200"}}}
```

Comment: user53102 さんと user53104 さんは同一人物でしょうか？ であればアカウントを統合して下さい。「 [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) 」をご参照下さい。

Answer (score 1):

すみません、自己解決しました。

質問時のjsonサンプルだと、以下のSQL文で想定した出力ができるようになりました。

```
select User, Books.History from `テーブル名`
where Books.History is not null
```